# What is the correct term for an 'overridden' class attribute in a child class?

Tags: oop

While exploring basic Object Oriented Design principles I was wondering: What is the correct term for an 'overridden' class attribute in a child class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's just that: an overridden property/attribute.  I don't think it has a specific term.